# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')"

Tags: javascript

ya busque por todos lados y la solucion dice que probablemente no haya id con ese nombre, pero en el .html si esta ese id, no se que hacer, dice que el error se encuentra en cuadrito.addEventListener("mouseup", levantarMouse); y en los sitios donde he buscado solo dice que es porque probablemente no haya id con ese nombre, pero revise y si esta el id, aqui puse el archivo de javascript y el archivo de html, no se que hacer.

```js
  cuadrito.addEventListener("mouseup", levantarMouse);
  cuadrito.addEventListener("mousedown", bajarMouse);
  cuadrito.addEventListener("mousemove", moverMouse);


  var cuadrito = document.getElementById("area_de_dibujo");
  var colores = document.getElementById("color_usuario");
  var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
  var papel = cuadrito.getContext("2d");
  var estado;
  var x;
  var y;
  console.log(colores);

  function dibujolineas(color, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal, lienzo)
  {
    lienzo.beginPath();
    lienzo.strokeStyle = colores;
    lienzo.lineWidth = 3;
    lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
    lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
    lienzo.stroke();
    lienzo.closePath();
  }

  function pulsarMouse(evento)
  {
    estado = 1;
    x = evento.layerX;
    y = evento.layerY;
  }

  function dibujarTeclado(evento)
  {
    if (estado == 1)
    {
      dibujolineas(colores, x , y , evento.layerX, evento.layerY)
    }
    else
    {
      x = evento.layerX
      y = evento.layerY
    }
  }
  function levantarMouse(evento)
  {
    estado = 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>dibuja con teclas!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>selecciona el color:
      <input type="color" id="color_usuario"</input>
    <canvas id="area_de_dibujo" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <p>mueve las flechas del teclado para dibujar</p>
    <script src="teclas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente te sale un error porque la variable **cuadrito** que tienes en la primera línea aún no está definida. debes pasar las primeras tres líneas después de declarar la variable **cuadrito**.

Comenté las otras dos líneas porque sucede algo similar, te va a salir error si las funciones **bajarMouse** y **moverMouse** aún no están declaradas.

```js
var cuadrito = document.getElementById("area_de_dibujo");
var colores = document.getElementById("color_usuario");
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var papel = cuadrito.getContext("2d");
var estado;
var x;
var y;
console.log(colores);

cuadrito.addEventListener("mouseup", levantarMouse);
//cuadrito.addEventListener("mousedown", bajarMouse);
//cuadrito.addEventListener("mousemove", moverMouse);

function dibujolineas(color, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal, lienzo) {
  lienzo.beginPath();
  lienzo.strokeStyle = colores;
  lienzo.lineWidth = 3;
  lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
  lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
  lienzo.stroke();
  lienzo.closePath();
}

function pulsarMouse(evento) {
  estado = 1;
  x = evento.layerX;
  y = evento.layerY;
}

function dibujarTeclado(evento) {
  if (estado == 1) {
    dibujolineas(colores, x, y, evento.layerX, evento.layerY)
  } else {
    x = evento.layerX
    y = evento.layerY
  }
}

function levantarMouse(evento) {
  estado = 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dibuja con teclas!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>selecciona el color:
    <input type="color" id="color_usuario" </input>
    <canvas id="area_de_dibujo" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <p>mueve las flechas del teclado para dibujar</p>
    <script src="teclas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias por la aclaracion, ya pude definir esas tres lineas, pero aun me sale un error, en la linea  lienzo.beginPath(); ya que tampoco esta definida, el problema es que no se como definir esta linea, y pienso que tal vez hayan mas lineas que tampoco esten definidas. quiero hacer una pagina para hacer un dibujo siimple con el mouse, pero aun no he podido solucionar el problema de utilizar el mouse como pincel, apenas estoy entrando en la programacion y es dificil :c

Comment: Por lo que he visto en tu código y en tus preguntas, creo que estás siguiendo un curso en línea que en algún momento de mi vida también hice... Anímate a continuar con el curso sin saltarte los vídeos y evitando copiar y pegar el código. Te garantizo que vas a comprender todos los conceptos que ofrece el curso. Por otro lado, te animo a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de la comunidad para que conozcas cómo funciona. Vas a aprender las reglas y de paso vas ganando reputación. Ánimo que esta industria es maravillosa!